# Routine to compare new and old string values, maintain old data if nothing new

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Form which allows users to enter new Data for a record.  In order to maintain Data Integrity, I copy all the pre-existing Data (if Any) into the Record and overwrite only those fields which the user has added new Data to.  This new Record is saved to the database and the old Record Deleted.

I'm merely trying to find the most efficient way of going through each field to :

- determine if there is Current Data to Maintain
- New Data to Overwrite

I'll need to write the same type of Check for String, Decimal, Date and Integer (all nullable)

Here's my string check

```
 Private Function CreateRecordforSubmission() As Business.Casualty

    Dim c As Business.Casualty = Casualty

    c.alias = CheckStringValues(c.alias, txtAlias.Text.Trim())
    Return c

End Function
Private Function CheckStringValues(OldValue As String, newValue As String) As String

    If Not OldValue Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) Then

        '<-- There is NEW DATA
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) Then
            Return newValue
        Else
            '<-- No NEW DATA, check of there is CURRENT DATA to maintain
            If Not OldValue Is Nothing Then
                Return OldValue
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End If

    Else
        '<-- NO CURRENT DATA AND no changes have been made
        Return String.Empty
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm being moved to another project with more pressing dates so I wont be able to comment on the code beyond what has already been published.  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how CSLA does it. Each property in your object could take care of that comparison, if the setter detect a change or new value, you can update your variable and mark your object as modified.

```
Public Property Alias As String
    Get
        Return _alias
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) AndAlso _alias <> value Then
            _alias = value
            _objectWasModified = True
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

The If statement could be in the base class, or a helper class.

If you want to have a generic function for other type, here's an example. This assume that you are using nullable values.

```
Public Property Number As Integer?
    Get
        Return _number
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer?)
        If Not IsNullOrSame(Of Integer)(_number, value)Then
            _number= value
            _objectWasModified = True
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Function IsNullOrSame(Of T As Structure)(ByVal oldValue As Nullable(Of T), ByVal newValue As Nullable(Of T))

    If newValue.HasValue Then
        If Not oldValue.HasValue OrElse Not oldValue.Value.Equals(newValue.Value) Then
            Return False
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Although your proposal is not bad, it is not answering the main problem here: how to account for nulls of all the listed types? By assuming that other than `Nothing` each type has its special null-like value. For example: 0 for `Integer` & `Decimal`. That is: how to apply `IsNullOrEmpty` to types different than `String`?

Comment: @varocarbas 0 is different than null. If you want a null integer, it has to be a nullable type and all nullable type have HasValue as their properties.

Comment: Logically (this is evident for anyone), but within the context of the asked question is the same. That's why `IsNullOrEmpty` is being used: you are not only looking for nulls (`Nothing`), but also for what is conventionally assumed as null in the given type (e.g., empty string). The intention of the OP is extending this kind of functionalities to other types. The equivalence of an empty string in `Decimal`/`Integer` is zero. Thus, you haven't answered the question at all (i.e., how do I modify this function to account for other types?), but proposed a non-requested alternative.

Comment: @varocarbas this is a very big assumption, I've seen system where they considered -1 as null/empty, not 0. I won't change anything until he specify it in his question. His "question" actually has no question marks, we don't know if he actually wants us to update his function to handle other type or if he just want a better alternative to what he is doing at the moment, which is what I'm giving to him (and following the title of the question). If you think I didn't answer properly, you can write one and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I mean... whatever the OP wants. What is clear is that `IsNullOrEmpty` accounts for more than just nulls and the question states "I'll need to write the same type of Check for String, Decimal, Date and Integer". I think that your answer has a valid point, but needs some tweaking to properly address the concerns here. PS: I did write my answer, but deleted it (if your rep would be higher than 10K you could see it now :)) because I changed my mind (reason is irrelevant). Additionally as said, you are raising a valid point, just need to account for all the involved issues (= extend it a bit).